# Month automatically increasing in phpmyadmin database table

Tags: php, html

Is there any way to increase a table field named month every month..or I should say to the latest month...Just need to update the month value..i.e. In, it should be 1

march 3

July 7

etc.

Help me.

Comment: [How to Create Scheduled Events in MySQL](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest you'll get without manually inserting [**idate**('m')](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.idate.php) with every new record and without using fancy mysql... is by using mysql default TIMESTAMP field. Check this out:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

But this a date so you'll need to use **MONTH(`Field`)** to get the month.